# Склонение географических названий

Tags: имена-собственные

В г. Павлоград(е) открыли новый мост через реку Волчья(ю).

В городе Павлоград(е) открыли новый мост через реку Волчья(ю).

Склоняются ли названия городов, если перед ними стоит определяющее слово а) в сокращенном виде - [г.] б) полностью - [городе]? Если склоняются, то в любые падежи? Нужно ли склонение в случае родительного падежа: г. Павлограда, города Павлограда? И насчет реки я тоже сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Названия  г о р о д о в,  выраженные склоняемым существительным, как правило, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом, например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом. То же при иноязычных названиях: в городе Барселоне, близ города Венеции. 
   Обычно не согласуют редко встречающиеся названия, чтобы сохранить нужную ясность; ср. в периодической печати: Переговоры имели место в городе Мина (Саудовская Аравия; при сочетании «в городе Мине» начальная форма незнакомого слова могла бы быть воспринята и как Мин, и как Мина); к пребыванию в России мэра греческого города Волос; поезд подходит к городу Кальтанисетта; близ города Ниш; в румынском курортном городе Синая.

Answer (score 2):

Полное или сокращенное родовое название (город/г.) на выбор формы приложения (название города) не влияет.

> В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А.
> Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой указано,
> что «сокращение г. (город), как и
> полное слово, рекомендуется
> употреблять ограниченно, главным
> образом перед названиями городов,
> образованными от фамилий (г. Киров)».

[link text](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90)

Павлоград склоняется — в г./городе Павлограде. Ср. в г. Санкт-Петербурге, г. Владивостоке.

[link text](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.3)

Река Волчья склоняется: через реку Волчью. Ср. на реке Светлой. Там же [link text](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.3)

Comment: По сути не спорю, но область применения родового слова "город" гораздо шире. на делезной дороге, например, принято именно "город Москва" по той причине что без родового слова там употребляются названия *станций*. Плсю военные. Плюс случаи общих названий для например, рек, и городов на них стоящих. 
По сути рекомендации, повторюсь, не спорю. Склонять при родовом слове надо и реку, и город. и вообще почти всякий населённый пункт. С другими топонимами - возможны варианты. Ссылки - те же.